# Displaying Fragments with data in a ViewPager on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-lifecycle

So in my MainActivity OnCreate I create 3 Fragments, each filled with different data. I then  add these Fragments to my ViewPagerAdapter.

```
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    MealsFragment exploreFragment = null;
    MealsFragment favoriteFragment = null;
    MealsFragment localFragment = null;

    //if there is no saved instance, create fragments with passed data as args and add them to the viewpageradapter
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        exploreFragment = fetchExploreMealsDataAndCreateFragment();
        favoriteFragment = fetchFavoriteMealsDataAndCreateFragment();
        localFragment = fetchLocalMealsDataAndCreateFragment();
    }

    //add fragments to the adapter
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(exploreFragment, "EXPLORE");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(favoriteFragment, "FAVORITES");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(localFragment, "LOCAL");

    //set adapter to the viewpager and link it with the different tabs
    mviewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    mtabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mviewPager);
```

The 3 different fetch methods get the data from an API or DB, so I don't want to call these methods every time I rotate my screen and go through my lifecycle. That's why I firstly check if the savedInstanceState is null. But what happens now is that if my savedInstanceState is not null, the Fragments will be null since i initialised them that way.

Apparently this is not a problem since when I rotate the screen, the fragments remain the same. I was wondering what is going on here behind the scenes as I don't think this is the correct way of handling my situation. Any suggestions of improvement are appreciated aswell.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that ViewPagerAdapter is my own implementation of FragmentPageAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return fragmentList.get(i);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragmentList.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
    fragmentList.add(fragment);
    fragmentTitleList.add(title);
}
```

}

Comment: What is `ViewPagerAdapter`? Is that some library class?

Comment: Forgot to mention, my bad. It's my own class I created that implements from FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: How it works will be important for this question. Could you post it?

Comment: Posted it in the EDIT section of the post

Comment: `ViewPagerAdapter.addFragment()` is an anti-pattern and should NEVER be used. Refer to the accepted answer to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering what is going on here behind the scenes

Alright, so, this is going to involve looking at the source for `FragmentPagerAdapter`. What's relevant is the implementation of the `instantiateItem()` method... though really just a portion of it.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    [...]

    // Do we already have this fragment?
    String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId);
    Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
    if (fragment != null) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Attaching item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
        mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);
    } else {
        fragment = getItem(position);
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Adding item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
        mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment,
                makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId));
    }

    [...]
}
```

Essentially, the `getItem()` method from your `ViewPagerAdapter` is only called once for each position for the lifetime of the Activity (even across configuration changes). Every time other than the first, the `Fragment` object is retrieved directly from the `FragmentManager` as opposed to the Adapter.

So yes, for all re-creations of your Activity, your Adapter is holding a `List<Fragment>` that is just `null`, `null`, `null`... but it doesn't matter, because this list is not accessed again.

**HOWEVER**

The above statements assume that every Fragment in your adapter was constructed and added to the `FragmentManager` *before* your configuration change, and this is *not necessarily* guaranteed.

By default, the off-screen page limit for the `ViewPager` is `1`. That means that your third page (your `localFragment`), is not necessarily added to the `ViewPager`, and therefore the `FragmentManager`, on first launch. If you scroll over to the next page even one time, it will be, but this is not necessarily true.

Or perhaps you have manually set the off-screen page limit to be `2`, in which case all the pages/Fragments will be added immediately.

---

Probably the best thing to do is to change how you're using `FragmentPagerAdapter` altogether. I'd put this inside your `Activity` as an inner class:

```
private class ExampleAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ExampleAdapter() {
        super(getSupportFragmentManager());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return fetchExploreMealsDataAndCreateFragment();
            case 1: return fetchFavoriteMealsDataAndCreateFragment();
            case 2: return fetchLocalMealsDataAndCreateFragment();

            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected position: " + position);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return "EXPLORE";
            case 1: return "FAVORITES";
            case 2: return "LOCAL";

            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected position: " + position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

And then your `onCreate()` could be changed to this:

```
FragmentPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ExampleAdapter();
mviewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
mtabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mviewPager);
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that you only call the "fetch and create" methods on demand, but still have the ability to call them after a configuration change in situations where they weren't loaded before the configuration change.